# android: Query SMS Unique DisplayName(s) Efficiently

Tags: android, listview, sms, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying to write an activity that shows the DisplayNames of contacts evolved in SMS conversations.

Unfortunately:

1. The SMS database doesn't contain the DisplayName

   *so I used a function that uses the address "phone number" to get the DisplayName*
2. I don't know how to query unique addresses from the SMS database

   *so I used sorted query, used a loop to find unique DisplayNames, and then put them in an array*

If not, is it better to run this process in the background? but how will the activity open if the list is not prepared yet?!

**Finally, I used this array in an ArrayAdapter to populate my ListView (pretty much trying to mimic the native Messaging app)**

The activity turned out to take a lot of time to open up (around 2-3 seconds, and I don't have much messages)

Is there a way to solve any or both of my problems efficiently?

---

## Here's my code

---

```
public class MessagesPicker extends Activity {
    
    Cursor myCursor;
    ListView pickerListView;
    public static final String MessageAddress = address;
    public static final String MessageID = _id;
    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.picker);
        
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        myCursor = cr.query(Uri.parse(contentsms), null, null, null, MessageAddress +  ASC); //getting sorted data to easy finding uniqueness
        
        /**setting up unique DisplayNames array**/
        int allCount = myCursor.getCount(), uniqueCount = 0;        
        String[] uniqueNames = new String[allCount];
        String temp1,temp2;
        myCursor.moveToFirst();
        temp1 = getContactDiplayNameByAddr();
        uniqueNames[uniqueCount++] = temp1;
        do {
            temp2 = getContactDiplayNameByAddr();
            if (temp1.compareTo(temp2) != 0){
                uniqueNames[uniqueCount++] = temp2;
                temp1 = temp2;
            }
        }while(myCursor.moveToNext());
       
        String [] valuesArray = new String[uniqueCount];    //filling the array
        for (int i = 0 ; i  uniqueCount ; i++)
            valuesArray[i] = uniqueNames[i];
        
        /**setting up the ListView**/
        ArrayAdapterString adapter = new ArrayAdapterString(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, valuesArray);
        pickerListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.PickerLV); //linking the object to the interface
        pickerListView.setAdapter(adapter);                     //setting the adapter
        pickerListView.setItemsCanFocus(false);                 //allowing to check the checkbox
        pickerListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);    //allowing multiple choices
    
    }
    
    String getContactDiplayNameByAddr() { //this function returns DisplayName, or if not available, returns the address
        
        String Address = myCursor.getString(myCursor.getColumnIndex(address));
        Uri personUri = Uri.withAppendedPath( ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Address);  
        Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(personUri,  
                                    new String[] {PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME},  
                                    null, null, null );  
        if( cur.moveToFirst() ) {  
            String DisplayName = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));  
            cur.close();  
            return DisplayName;  
       }  
       return Address; 
    }
}
```

Comment: The SMS/MMS application uses a local cache - it doesn't repeatedly query to separate providers to obtain the name.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I ended up doing :)